# Internal Server Error while Listing the Function App Keys in Azure Government

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-gov

I am trying to deploy a Http triggered Azure Function App in Azure Government through ARM template. Initially I got the name conflict error **There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved: 'sftestgovstorage.file.core.windows.net'**. I tried to solve this error by following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400201/arm-template-incorrect-storage-endpoint-for-appsettings-website-contentshare). After which I tried listing the function app keys and tried creating a new key. I am getting the error message **Internal Server Error**.

I even tried adding the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING setting into configuration with the storage account connection string with suffix **;EndpointSuffix=core.usgovcloudapi.net**. But I am still not able to list or create new function app keys.

I am using the following code to create a new function key

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
var response = await 
_client.PostAsync($"https://functionAppName.azurewebsites.us/admin/host/keys/{keyName}", null);
```

The ARM template used is

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#", 
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0", 
"parameters": {
"coreFunctionApp_appServicePlanName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Name of the app service plan to host core function app."      
     },
  "defaultValue": "SL360-Prod-BAM-Appsvc"
},
"coreFunctionApp_applicationInsightsName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Name of the application insights for the core function 
  app."
  },
  "defaultValue": "SL360-Prod-BAM-AppInsights"
},
"coreFunctionAppName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Name of the core function app"
  },
  "defaultValue": "SL360-Prod-BAM-FunApp"
},
"BAMConnectionString": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "BAM Connection String"
  },
  "defaultValue": "SL360-BAMConnectionString"
},
"storageAccountName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Name of the Storage account namespace"
  },
  "defaultValue": "SL360-Prod-BAM-Storage"
},
"storageContainerName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Name of the Storage account container"
  },
  "defaultValue": "SL360-Prod-BAM-Storage-container"
},
"storageAccountType": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
  "allowedValues": [
    "Standard_LRS",
    "Standard_GRS",
    "Standard_RAGRS"
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Storage Account type"
  }
}
},
"variables": {
"storageAccountid": "
[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', 
parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
"serverFarmApiVersion": "2018-02-01",
"storageApiVersion": " 
[providers('Microsoft.Storage','storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]]",
"sitesApiVersion": "2018-11-01",
"insightsApiVersion": "2015-05-01"
},
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('storageApiVersion')]",
  "kind": "Storage",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
  }
},
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('serverFarmApiVersion')]",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[parameters('coreFunctionApp_appServicePlanName')]",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('coreFunctionApp_appServicePlanName')]",
    "computeMode": "Dynamic"
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "Y1",
    "tier": "Dynamic"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
},
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('insightsApiVersion')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[parameters('coreFunctionApp_applicationInsightsName')]",
  "properties": {
    "Application_Type": "web",
    "ApplicationId": " 
   [parameters('coreFunctionApp_applicationInsightsName')]"
  },
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('coreFunctionAppName'))]": "Resource"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components"
},    {

  "apiVersion": "[variables('sitesApiVersion')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 
parameters('coreFunctionApp_appServicePlanName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', 
parameters('coreFunctionApp_applicationInsightsName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 
parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
  ],
  "kind": "functionapp",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[parameters('coreFunctionAppName')]",
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 
parameters('coreFunctionApp_appServicePlanName'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', 
parameters('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
        },
        {
          "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', 
parameters('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
        },
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
          "value": "~2"
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
          "value": "6.5.0"
        },
        {
          "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
          "value": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', 
parameters('coreFunctionApp_applicationInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey]"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
},
],
"outputs": 
"StorageAccessKey": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 
parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"
}
}
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Difficult to debug without seeing your exact ARM template. The URI should have above is wrong.

Comment: The uri works for other function apps @SteveMichelotti

Comment: @SteveMichelotti I have added the ARM template used for deploying the function app.  The deployment was successful with Function app being created